# Arduino : Incorrectly formatted json

Tags: c++, json, arduino

I'm trying to write an arduino code (c++) that produces json to match the format required by influxdb.

This is the code I have so far

```
#include <ArduinoJson.h>
StaticJsonDocument<200> doc;
JsonArray fields = doc.createNestedArray("fields");
JsonArray tags = doc.createNestedArray("tags");
JsonArray array = doc.to<JsonArray>();
JsonObject nested = array.createNestedObject();
nested["Machinename"] = "Quench tank";
nested["Machinetype"] = "Quench";
fields.add("temp");
```

This is the desired format

```
{
       measurement: "Quench1",
       fields: {
           temp: 5.5,

       },
        tags:{
            Machinename:"Machine"
           Machinetype:"Machine1"
       },
        timestamp: new Date()
    }
```

But this is what I'm actually getting

```
[
  {
    "Machinename": "⸮⸮\b",
    "Machinetype": "Machine1"
  }
]
```

Comment: Your desired output does not contain any arrays, so it is a bit weird to see array-related code. Furthermore, I think `doc.to<JsonArray>()` or the subsequent operations on it will nuke the object that was there before.

Comment: If you don't want an array, why do you make arrays?

Comment: Botje - I'll be honest, I'm new to this, and don't really know what I'm doing, beyond what I've found online. I copied the array related code from an example.

Comment: Lightness Races in Orbit - a very valid question, and not one I really have an answer to

Comment: So I don't need arrays - noted